# Deu Problema no Meu C# Script do Video do Nils(No Board Manager)

Tags: c#, unity3d, recuperação-de-erros

Nils , ou alguem que saiba me responder , esta acontecendo varios erros aqui na minha aba do console , Sou novo nesta area e esta falando algo sobre erros com ) ] } e coisas tipo basicas de programação! por favor me ajude a resolver isto ! preciso muito.

[Este é o video Referente a tal Script de C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_nXuYgfLh8%20%3C--%20O%20Video%20que%20Ele%20ensina%20a%20fazer%20o%20script).

[image: Esta é a imagem dos erros que te falei.]

e tambem vou mandar todo o script que tenho aqui feito .

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System; //Atributo serializable - como aparecem as variaveis no inspector e no editor
    using System.Collections.Generic; //usar Lists.
    using Random = UnityEngine.Random; //Gerar numeros aleatorios
    public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {

    [Serializable]
    public class Count
    {
        public int minimum;
        public int maximum;

        public Count (int min, int max)
        {
            minimum = min;
            maximum = max;
        }

    }

    public int columns = 8; //Quantidade de Colunas do Tabuleiro
    public int rows = 8; //linhas no tabuleiro
    public Count wallCount = new Count (5,9); //Quantidade aleatoria de numeros internos
    public Count foodCount = new Count (1,5); //Quantidade aleatoria de comida(Nao irei Utilizar)
    public GameObject exit;
    public GameObject[] floorTiles; //Chao
    public GameObject[] WallTile; //Muros
    public GameObject[] foodTiles; //Comidas
    public GameObject[] enemyTile; //inimigos
    public GameObject[] outerWallsTiles; //Muros Externos

    private Transform boardHolder; //Variavel para pendurar todo mundo do tabuleiro
    private List <Vector3> gridPosition = new List<Vector3>(); //Lista de Possiveis Posiçoes para os tiles


    //Limpar lista do grid e preparar para garar um novo tabuleiro
    void initialiseList()
    {
        //Limpa as posiçoes
        gridPosition.Clear ();

        //loop para navegar as colunas
        for (int x = 1; x < columns -1; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 1; y<rows-1;y++)
            {

                gridPosition.Add(new Vector3(x,y,0f));
            }

        }
    }

    //configurar background e muros externos
    void BoardSetup()
    {
        //inicializa o tabuleiro e atribiu seu transform
        boardHolder = new GameObject ("Board").transform;

        for(int x = -1, x < columns + 1;x++);
        for(int y = -1, y < columns + 1;y++);
                //Pegar tile aleatorio para fazer parte do chao
                GameObject toInstatiate = floorTiles[Random.Range(0,floorTiles.Length)];

                //verificar se e muro externo
        if( x == -1 || y == -1 || x == columns || y == rows );
                {
                    toInstatiate = outerWallsTiles[Random.Range[0,outerWallsTiles.Length]];


                GameObject instance = Instantiate(toInstatiate, new Vector3(x,y,0f),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;

                instance.transform.SetParent (boardHolder);
                }
    }

    //Rertorna um valor aleatorio da nossa gridposition
    Vector3 RandomPosition()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range (0, gridPosition.Count);

        Vector3 randomPosition = gridPosition [randomIndex];

        gridPosition.RemoveAt (randomIndex);

        return randomPosition;

    }

    //pega o array de objetos que passar, junto com o valor minimo e maximo que voce vai adicionar daaquele numero de objeto.
    LayoutObjectAtRandom[GameObject tileArray, int minimum, int maximum]
    {
        int objectCount = Random.Range (minimum, maximum);

        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) 
        {
            Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition ();

            GameObject tileChoice = tileArray[Random.Range(0, tileArray.Length)];

            Instantiate(tileChoice, randomPosition,Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    public void SetupScene(int level)
    {
        //colocou os quadradinhos do tabuleiro
        BoardSetup ();
        //inicializou o grid
        initialiseList ();

        //instanciar um numero aleatorio de muros internos
        LayoutObjectAtRandom(WallTile wallCount.minimum, wallCount.maximum);

        //instanciar um numero aleatorio de comidas
        LayoutObjectAtRandom (foodTiles, foodCount.minimum, foodCount.maximum);

        //instanciar o numero decimal inimigos baseado No level
        int enemyCount = (int)Mathf.Log(level, 2f);
        LayoutObjectAtRandom (enemyTile, enemyCount, enemyCount);

        //instanciar a saida
        Instantiate (exit, new Vector3 (columns-1,rows-1,0f),Quaternion.identity);

    }


    }


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
```

Espero Sua Resposta . Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Esses erros devem estar acontecendo porque você não está fechando a `classe` e o `namespace` corretamente.

Os códigos abaixo desta linha não está no escopo da `classe`.

```
 public int columns = 8; //Quantidade de Colunas do Tabuleiro
```

De uma verificada onde a abertura da sua `classe` está e onde o fechamento se encontra.

Ajeitei o código, de uma olhada no seu código e compara com o que está abaixo, principalmente preste atenção nas aberturas `{` e fechamento `}` das chaves.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System; //Atributo serializable - como aparecem as variaveis no inspector e no editor
using System.Collections.Generic; //usar Lists.
using Random = UnityEngine.Random; //Gerar numeros aleatorios

public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {
    [Serializable]
    public class Count
    {
        public int minimum;
        public int maximum;

        public Count (int min, int max)
        {
            minimum = min;
            maximum = max;
        }

// Você estava fechando a classe nesta linha

        public int columns = 8; //Quantidade de Colunas do Tabuleiro
        public int rows = 8; //linhas no tabuleiro
        public Count wallCount = new Count (5,9); //Quantidade aleatoria de numeros internos
        public Count foodCount = new Count (1,5); //Quantidade aleatoria de comida(Nao irei Utilizar)
        public GameObject exit;
        public GameObject[] floorTiles; //Chao
        public GameObject[] WallTile; //Muros
        public GameObject[] foodTiles; //Comidas
        public GameObject[] enemyTile; //inimigos
        public GameObject[] outerWallsTiles; //Muros Externos

        private Transform boardHolder; //Variavel para pendurar todo mundo do tabuleiro
        private List <Vector3> gridPosition = new List<Vector3>(); //Lista de Possiveis Posiçoes para os tiles


        //Limpar lista do grid e preparar para garar um novo tabuleiro
        void initialiseList()
        {
            //Limpa as posiçoes
            gridPosition.Clear ();

            //loop para navegar as colunas
            for (int x = 1; x < columns -1; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 1; y<rows-1;y++)
                {
                    gridPosition.Add(new Vector3(x,y,0f));
                }
            }
        }

        //configurar background e muros externos
        void BoardSetup()
        {
            //inicializa o tabuleiro e atribiu seu transform
            boardHolder = new GameObject ("Board").transform;

            for(int x = -1, x < columns + 1;x++);
            for(int y = -1, y < columns + 1;y++);

            //Pegar tile aleatorio para fazer parte do chao
            GameObject toInstatiate = floorTiles[Random.Range(0,floorTiles.Length)];

            //verificar se e muro externo
            if( x == -1 || y == -1 || x == columns || y == rows );
            {
                toInstatiate = outerWallsTiles[Random.Range[0,outerWallsTiles.Length]];

                GameObject instance = Instantiate(toInstatiate, new Vector3(x,y,0f),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;

                instance.transform.SetParent (boardHolder);
            }
        }

        //Rertorna um valor aleatorio da nossa gridposition
        Vector3 RandomPosition()
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range (0, gridPosition.Count);

            Vector3 randomPosition = gridPosition [randomIndex];

            gridPosition.RemoveAt (randomIndex);

            return randomPosition;
        }

        //pega o array de objetos que passar, junto com o valor minimo e maximo que voce vai adicionar daaquele numero de objeto.
        LayoutObjectAtRandom[GameObject tileArray, int minimum, int maximum]
        {
            int objectCount = Random.Range (minimum, maximum);

            for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) 
            {
                Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition ();

                GameObject tileChoice = tileArray[Random.Range(0, tileArray.Length)];

                Instantiate(tileChoice, randomPosition,Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

        public void SetupScene(int level)
        {
            //colocou os quadradinhos do tabuleiro
            BoardSetup ();
            //inicializou o grid
            initialiseList ();

            //instanciar um numero aleatorio de muros internos
            LayoutObjectAtRandom(WallTile wallCount.minimum, wallCount.maximum);

            //instanciar um numero aleatorio de comidas
            LayoutObjectAtRandom (foodTiles, foodCount.minimum, foodCount.maximum);

            //instanciar o numero decimal inimigos baseado No level
            int enemyCount = (int)Mathf.Log(level, 2f);
            LayoutObjectAtRandom (enemyTile, enemyCount, enemyCount);

            //instanciar a saida
            Instantiate (exit, new Vector3 (columns-1,rows-1,0f),Quaternion.identity);
        }

        // e o namespace aqui...

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

        }

    }// fecha a classe
}// fecha o namespace
```

Sempre preste atenção a esses detalhes.
Arrume isto, e veja se irá funcionar.